# Jackson producing empty XML with dropwizard but not in unit test

Tags: java, json, xml, jackson, dropwizard

I am seeing a problem with some fields that have been annotated with

```
@JsonSerialize
```

When the surrounding class is returned from a web-service as XML, but not in the unit test.  When the service is called with Accept header of "application/json" everything works fine.  When the service is called with an Accept header of "application/xml" the fields with the serializer specified are being stubbed with an empty XML tag.

Example code (simplified from real problem).

```
public abstract class AbstractEntity {
    private String name;

    @JsonSerialize(using = MyStampSerializer.class)
    private MyStamp created;

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public MyStamp getCreated() {
        return this.created;
    }

    public void setCreated(MyStamp created) {
        this.created = created;
    }
}

@Immutable
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@XmlRootElement(name = "entity")
public class Entity extends AbstractEntity {

    public Entity() {
        super();
    }        
}

public class MyStampSerializer extends JsonSerializer<RegistryStamp>
{
    @Override
    public void serialize(MyStamp stamp, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) 
        throws IOException
    {
        jgen.writeStartObject();
        jgen.writeStringField("name", stamp.getName());
        jgen.writeNumberField("timestamp", stamp.getTimestamp().getMillis());
        jgen.writeEndObject();
    }
}

public class EntityXMLTest {

    @Test
    public void serializeAndDeserializeTest() throws InvalidClassificationException, JsonProcessingException, IOException, InvalidNameException {
        Entity entity = buildTestEntity();  // Code not included.
        XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
        xmlMapper.registerModule(new RegistryModule());
        String xml = xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(collection);
        assertNotNull(xml);
        assertThat(xml, is("Hello"));
    }
}
```

So in the case that xml is requested from the web-service, the (incorrect) output looks like:

```
<entity>
    <name>theName</name>
    <created />
</entity>
```

But in the unit test, the (correct) output looks like:

```
<entity>
    <name>theName</name>
    <created>
        <name>otherName</name>
        <timestamp>8647567</timestamp>
    </created>
</entity>
```

JSON is as expected in both unit tests and web-service.

If I comment out the serializer and re-run the unit test, the output looks like:

```
<entity>
    <created>
        <name>test1</name>
        <timestamp>
            <dayOfYear>2</dayOfYear>
            <dayOfMonth>2</dayOfMonth>
            <dayOfWeek>5</dayOfWeek>
            <era>1</era>
            <year>1970</year>
            <weekOfWeekyear>1</weekOfWeekyear>
            <!-- snip ..... etc -->
        </timestamp>
    </created>
</entity>
```

So we clearly need the serializer to apply for the XML as well which is happening when I call XMLMapper directly in the unit test.

Is there some way to tell Jersery/Jackson to use the serializer for both XML and JSON?  Is there a way to find out why jackson is stubbing the XML for the fields with custom serializers?  Also, is there a way to configure the unit test so that it behaves in the same way as the dropwizard/Jersey/Jackson web-service?

Comment: So, do i understand that right: you want that the xml serialisation displays the created time as well?

Comment: @pandaadb Yes.  I've editied the question to make that a bit clearer.

Comment: Sorry, i have not been getting into writing an answer yet :/ Your issue might be related to the way DW is initialising its object mapper. You can start by trying to find the message body writer for the xml content type and step through that one. i hope i get to checking out what is happening there soonish and then answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I got it working.  Key points are:

If you want to use @JsonSerialize with jackson and dropwizard, you probably need to use the [dropwizard-xml](https://github.com/yunspace/dropwizard-xml/) extension bundle that is mentioned at the very bottom of the [jackson annotations page](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations/wiki/Jackson-Annotations)

After this a number of changes were required to get the XML to look right, mostly involving

```
@JacksonXmlProperty and 
@JacksonXmlElementWrapper
```

The final challenge was finding a version of dropwizard-xml that was compatible with the versions of jackson that I was using, *and* compiled with java 1.7 I found [0.9.0-30](http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/yunspace/dropwizard/dropwizard-xml/0.9.0-30/) useful.